# How can I set my email properly on both signup page and in cpanel without errors

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli, cpanel, web-deployment

I built my signup page with php and I want a user to get a confirmation email on signing up. Everything works well and the user receives the email which i want, but my worry is that in the email which the user receives, the sender's name is my cpanel username and the sender email is also listing my cpanel username like in the image i attached. Please guys I kindly need your help.
This is my image showing the image which the user receives immediately after signing up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvh2H.png)

This is my code

```
<?php

$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $pw2Err = $pw3Err = $mailtaken = "";
$fname = $lname = $email = $password = $pw2 = "";  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pw2 = $_POST['pw2'];

    //connecting to the database
    include_once ("../database/connect_db.php");

    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $fname = $_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $lname = $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $email = $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $password = $_POST['password']);
    $pw2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $pw2 = $_POST['pw2']);

    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
        $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
            $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {
        $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
            $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $passwordErr = "Your password is required";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['pw2'])) {
        $pw3Err = "Please confirm your password";
    } else {
        if ($password != $pw2) {
            $pw3Err = "Your passwords do not match!";
        } else {
            // generate vkey
            $vkey = md5(time().$fname);
            echo $vkey;
            $password = md5($password);

            $select = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
            $result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($result_check == 1) {
                $mailtaken = "The email you entered is already taken, if you already have an account please go to the log in page";
            
            } else {
                 $insert = mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO usertable 
                            (fname,lname,email,password,vkey) 
                 VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email', '$password','$vkey')"); 
 
                //  sending mail
                $to = $email;
                $subject = "Account Confirmation";
                $message = "<a href = 'http://localhost/bookcover/verify.php?vkey=$vkey'>Click to confirm</a>";
                $headers = "From: abcwebmaster111@gmail.com";
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
                $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset = UTF-8"."\r\n";
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                header("Location:../wel.php"); 
            }
            if ($insert) {
                Send email
            } else {
                echo "There was an error";
            }
       }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sign Up - Askees</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>
<style>
     .error {color: #ff0000;}
     h4 {color: #blue !important;}
</style>

<body>
<h2 align="center">SignUp to Askees</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <br>
                <p><span class="err"><h4> Please fill in the following form</span></h4></p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr; ?></span>
                    </div><div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lname;?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr; ?></span>
                    </div><div class="form-group">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr; echo $mailtaken;?></span>
                    </div><div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password;?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
                    </div><div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="pw2" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $pw2;?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $pw2Err; ?></span>
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $pw3Err; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Already have an account?</h3>
                        <p>Click <a href="login.php">HERE</a> to login</p>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                    <br>
        </div>
      </div>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: ohk thank you for that observation. I am trying to use prepared statements but did u see the image and look at the email which users receive? especially the se=nder email and the sender username

Comment: I would guess your hosting account's mailserver overwrote the from field with one from its own domain, since it's not valid to use a Gmail address when you're not sending from Gmail - it will make your mail look like spam or spoofing and be more likely to be blocked by the receiving server. Same if you used any other address from a different domain. set the from field to be something from your own domain - it needn't be a real mailbox, just `noreply@yourdomain.com`, that kind of thing. If you want to redirect replies to your Gmail, set that address in the email's reply-to field instead.